# contenteditable: save and restore caret position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable, caret

The function below causes the caret to move back to the beginning. How would I make it stay at the same spot after the function is called?

```
function highlightText() {
            var mystring = document.getElementById("writeArea").textContent;
            mystring = mystring.replace(/function/g , "<span class=\"func\">function</span>");
            document.getElementById("writeArea").innerHTML = mystring;
        }
```

Contenteditable declaration:

```
<div class="codeArea" id="writeArea" contenteditable="true"> <p> edit me! </p> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `selectionStart` to get and set the position of the caret:

```js
document.getElementById("writeArea").onkeyup = highlightText(this);
function highlightText(o) {
  var mystring = document.getElementById("writeArea").textContent,
  caretPosition = o.selectionStart;
  mystring = mystring.replace(/function/g , "<span class=\"func\">function</span>");
  document.getElementById("writeArea").innerHTML = mystring;
  document.getElementById("writeArea").selectionStart = caretPosition;
}
```

```html
<div class="codeArea" id="writeArea" contenteditable="true"> <p> edit me! </p> </div>
```

Comment: Sorry for the noob question, but what am I suppose to put for o? Google chrome just gave me an error of "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'selectionStart' of undefined".

Comment: A reference to the document object of your contentedi div

Comment: I tried on reactjs + Chrome and this does not work for contenteditable tags...it works for input tags if you add `document.getElementById("writeArea").selectionEnd = caretPosition;` as well